# Neo4J Cypher Exclude nodes that connect to a specific node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to find all nodes that don't connect to a specific node. I have an app where students doing an assignment discover themes in a story, and then write explications. Then, other students do peer reviews of these explications. My data looks like this:

```
Assignment-hasTheme->Theme-hasChild->Theme
Annotation-theme->Theme
Explication-owner->User
Explication-annotation->Annotation
PeerReview-explication->Explication
```

As part of the application, when a user has to do a peer review, I have to find all the explications written by other users. It seems to me like this query should work:

```
MATCH
  (u),
  (a)-[:hasTheme]->(:Theme)
     -[:hasChild*]->(:Theme)
     <-[:theme]-(ann:Annotation)
     <-[:annotation]-(e:Explication)
OPTIONAL MATCH
  (e)<-[:explication]-(p:PeerReview)
WHERE id(a)=7 AND id(u)=4
  AND (e)-[:owner]->(u)
RETURN e, count(e) AS explicationCount
ORDER BY explicationCount ASC
```

The problem is that it doesn't: I get all the explications that all users have written. That includes the explications the user wrote. Can anyone tell me how to exclude those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `WHERE` clause is only associated with one other clause...the preceding `MATCH`, `OPTIONAL MATCH`, or `WITH`. In your query, it's associated with the `OPTIONAL MATCH`.

If you re-read your query knowing this, you can see that the first `MATCH` has no `WHERE` clause, so it's matching on all assignments and all users, finding all explications.

THEN it does the optional match to get `:PeerReviews` matching on the given assignment and user ids where the explication owner is the user with the given id. The `WHERE` is only affecting which `:PeerReviews` (variable `p`) are matched.

A couple other things I can see...you're introducing a variable `ann` on the `:Annotations` matched in the pattern, and a variable `p` for the :`PeerReview`, but you're not actually doing anything with these in the query. This also makes your `OPTIONAL MATCH` useless, you're not returning or operating on the matched `:PeerReviews`.

My recommendation is to remove those variables and remove your `OPTIONAL MATCH` completely.

```
MATCH
  (u),
  (a)-[:hasTheme]->(:Theme)
     -[:hasChild*]->(:Theme)
     <-[:theme]-(:Annotation)
     <-[:annotation]-(e:Explication)
WHERE id(a)=7 AND id(u)=4
  AND (e)-[:owner]->(u)
RETURN e, count(e) AS explicationCount
ORDER BY explicationCount ASC
```

If you do want to add in the `OPTIONAL MATCH` and use the matched `:PeerReview`, ensure that it's below the `WHERE` affecting the `MATCH`, like so:

```
MATCH
  (u),
  (a)-[:hasTheme]->(:Theme)
     -[:hasChild*]->(:Theme)
     <-[:theme]-(:Annotation)
     <-[:annotation]-(e:Explication)
WHERE id(a)=7 AND id(u)=4
  AND (e)-[:owner]->(u)
OPTIONAL MATCH
  (e)<-[:explication]-(p:PeerReview)
RETURN e, count(e) AS explicationCount, p
ORDER BY explicationCount ASC
```

EDIT

In response to the comments where the desired result is each :Explication and the count of all linked :PeerReviews, you would use this query:

```
MATCH
  (u),
  (a)-[:hasTheme]->(:Theme)
     -[:hasChild*0..]->(:Theme)
     <-[:theme]-(:Annotation)
     <-[:annotation]-(e:Explication)
WHERE id(a)=7 AND id(u)=4
  AND (e)-[:owner]->(u)
OPTIONAL MATCH
  (e)<-[:explication]-(p:PeerReview)
RETURN e, count(p) as peerReviewCount
ORDER BY peerReviewCount ASC
```

EDIT

Updated the above query so it will find annotations on the parent theme as well instead of just its children.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I didn't try that. I guess I misunderstood from the Cypher documentation--I thought WHERE applied to all MATCH clauses. The extra variables were the result of some extra things I wanted to do in the query. Also, my goal with the OPTIONAL MATCH is related to counting the number of reviews each explication has (that's something I left out here).

Comment: It's a fairly common misunderstanding, I made the same assumption you did when I started with Cypher. There are a couple gotchas like that which aren't obvious from the documentation that you'll only run into when you start creating your own queries.

Comment: One other thing...your returning `e` and `count(e)` could be a problem, as it's one Explication per line, so I think the count will be 1 for each line.

Comment: Thank you! I'm actually trying to return e, and the number of p linked to each e. What would be the right way to do that?

Comment: I added this to my answer. Hope that helps!

Comment: One thing I noticed, though, your pattern in the first MATCH will only find :Annotations of children of the :Theme of the :Assignment, but not :Annotations of the :Theme itself. Do you need that fixed?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes, I would like to do that. Could you fix that?

Comment: Fixed in the last query. It's just a matter of using *0.. for the variable length relationship, so it will also match on the theme parent node itself instead of just its children.